# How to play video in lightbox from uploads folder of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, video, lightbox

I tried using different plugins but all plugins view the videos from youtube or Vimeo. I am having videos in my uploads folder and want to play when clicked on link to them. Everytime I click on the link, it downloads the video instead of playing. Can anybody help?

Thanks